# Java Pattern and Matcher no result

Tags: java, regex

i'm writing this Java program for fun and i'm trying to get groups of substring with a regex.
My string is read from a file and it's something like:

`\t<firstName type="String">John</firstName>`

where \t is a tab.

I wrote this code to isolate the needed substring, but while on online testing it works, in my code it says "no matches".

```
try {
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(".+<(.+) type=\"(.+)\">(.+)</(.+)>");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

    String name = m.group(1);
    String type = m.group(2);
    String value = m.group(3);

    System.out.println("\"" + line + "\" matched regex");
    
} catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println("\"" + line + "\" didn't match regex");
}
```

My output is:

```
"   <firstName type="String">John</firstName>" didn't match regex
"   <surname type="String">Doe</surname>" didn't match regex
"   <age type="int">18</age>" didn't match regex
```

Do you have any clue?

Comment: this looks like a for loop. Probably you are in NullPointer or IndexOutOfBound due to the direct access to the element of a list that does not exists. If you parse lines one by one, you'll have only one group each time.

Comment: where do you test it online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just created a matcher in this line: `Matcher m = r.matcher(line)`. If you print the exception, you'll see `No match found` message.

You are using `m.group()` without calling `matches()` method.

Try this:

```
try {

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(".+<(.+) type=\\\"(.+)\\\">(.+)</(.+)>");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.matches()) {

        String name = m.group(1);
        String type = m.group(2);
        String value = m.group(3);
        System.out.println("\"" + line + "\" matched regex");
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("\"" + line + "\" didn't match regex");
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!
I didn't know that m.matches was mandatory. Thank you!